# Getting cron format from datetimes format using javascript

Tags: javascript, cron

Anyone know of any existing solutions using javascript that can parse a datetime and return cron format instances?

Like I have
start date 2019-09-04 01:00:00, then it will return * 1-2 */1 * *,

Comment: Your given date and your given cron-format are not compatible.

Comment: So if I provide start date 2019-09-09 14:59:00 and the next date 2019-09-10 14:59:00 , then how can I convert this to a corn format - Please help me regarding this. - @uprego

Comment: That's a good question. Dunno how, but there seem to be services to do the reverse thing in case you think you're near what you need. Example https://crontab.guru